# How to create a message template with drap and drop fields html 5 jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I want to create a template builder in html5 and `jquery`.In that i need to drag and drop fields in to the template,for example

In textarea,

> Dear {username},
>
> ```
>    Your account {Account ID} has been enabled.
> ```

I need to build ui with controls for various fields (like username ,account id) and i need to drop those fields into the textarea instead of '{}' texts.

[image]

Any Ideas? Not Particularly Drag & Drop, If any other ideas to achieve the same, please let me know.

Please refer this image to get a clear understanding of what i'm saying.Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: have you checked [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to) yet? this example shows how to drag and drop with snap to grid

Comment: not particularly drag and drop..if there is any other solutions to achieve the same functionality also highly appreciated

Comment: I'm sorry it's hard to understand if you say "In that i need to drag and drop fields[...]and i need to drop those fields" and after "Not Particularly Drag & Drop[...]"

Comment: i meant to say,instead of drag & drop if there is any other solution to create a template then that's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this site [link](http://skfox.com/2008/11/26/jquery-example-inserting-text-with-drag-n-drop/).

Hope that can help you

Comment: try to give example with discussion. Not just a link. :)